# Returning pending promises in async await

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, es6-promise

I am learning to use async / await and am having issues when trying to make an api request to set up my twilio device. Given the below code block, when I call `device()`, I get the following error message:

```
Uncaught 
TwilioException {message: "Capability token is not valid or missing."}
message
:
"Capability token is not valid or missing."
__proto__
:
Object
```

I believe this is due to the fact that the json returned in the `device` function is still shown as pending. How do I resolve this and what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

**Code block:**

```
import {Device} from 'twilio-client';

const api = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('/api/twilio');
    const json = await response.json();
    if (response.status === 403) {
      twilioConnectionFailure('Twilio has not been purchased.');
    }
    return json;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Connection failed: ${error.message}`);
    throw Error(error.message);
  }
};

const device = () => {
  const json = api();
  Device.setup(json.token);
  return Device;
};

export default device;
```

Comment: All async functions return a promise.  You have to use `.then()` or `await` on that promise to get the value from it.  `async/await` don't magically turn an asynchronous function into a synchronous one.  It's still asynchronous and returns a promise.  And, your function returns the promise BEFORE the async value is even available.

Answer (score 2):

The `api` function is still asynchronous and returns a promise - you need to wait for it:

```
export default async function device() {
  const json = await api();
//             ^^^^^
  Device.setup(json.token);
  return Device;
}
```